# Uranium accumulating inside a White Dwarf?

Tags: supernova, stellar-evolution, stellar-astrophysics, white-dwarf

A couple of days ago, there was news that "[Some dead stars may harbor enough uranium to set off a thermonuclear bomb](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2021/03/some-dead-stars-may-harbor-enough-uranium-set-thermonuclear-bomb)", which is basically a teaser for *[Actinide crystallization and fission reactions in cooling white dwarf stars](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.02122)* where the authors conclude:

> The first solids that form as a white dwarf (WD) starts to crystallize are greatly enriched in
> actinides because of their large charges. We estimate that
> these first solids could be so enriched in actinides that
> they may support a fission chain reaction. This reaction
> could ignite carbon burning and lead to the explosion of
> an isolated WD in a thermonuclear supernova.

Going through manuscript, it looks to me that this conclusion is drawn from molecular dynamics simulations  of a cube of up to $10^4$ ions. **What exactly is the line of argumentation of these microscopic observations from computer simulations are to macroscopic effects in the star?**

I understand, that a main question of the research was, whether a certain scenario is actually possible (inside a white dwarf), or literally

> Could uranium, [...], accumulate inside a white dwarf?

Just to clarify: I am not doubting the conclusion or questioning the method per se, I am just curious whether such an approach is usual for studying stellar evolution. Differently put: Is there a standard theory describing the conditions when the conditions are right for a white dwarf to explode?

#### Related

- [How are shockwaves in a star that cause supernova created](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/42018/37191)
- [Stellar life cycle flow chart with mass conditions and time scales](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40815/37191)

Comment: The line of argument is that there are no effects that would manifest themselves if they simulated a much larger number of nuclei plus electrons. i.e. There are no long range interactions other than gravity. Your second question is a different one. There are other papers that suggest an ignition temperature for carbon - which is mainly a study of quantum tunnelling probabilities. This paper just suggests that temperature will be exceeded.

Comment: @ProfRob For the MDS shown in the appendix of the arXiv-manuscript, can you tell which boundary conditions are used for the cube? Do I assume correctly that they use cyclic (toroidal) boundary-conditions or is it actually open boundaries? Which one do you use in general for such kind of problems?